# MYSQL - get three or more consecutive rows by time (on same date) where amount is minimum

Tags: mysql, min

I have a database with the following columns. I have added some sample data to show formatting.
**date**, **time**, **amount**
2021-10-14, 13:00, 15.40
2021-10-14, 13:01, 9.34
2021-10-14, 13:02, 10.12
2021-10-14, 13:03, 7.44

There are 2.6 million rows in the database spanning two years.
Each row is an increment of 1 minute.

**I need to write sql that will output and group rows that are continuous by minute for the same date, where the amount is greater than 8.00 and there are a minimum of 3 consecutive rows.**

This would then find an example like:
2021-11-30, 14:44, 8.04
2021-11-30, 14:45, 9.41
2021-11-30, 14:46, 9.27
2021-11-30, 14:47, 10.54
2021-11-30, 14:48, 11.09
2022-03-13, 08:22, 36.44
2022-03-13, 08:23, 17.38
2022-03-13, 08:24, 11.86

Comment: I have been looking at the Gaps and Island problem as a way to solve this... Found this article and hope I am on the right track. https://towardsdatascience.com/gaps-and-islands-with-mysql-b407040d133d

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So if I understand correctly you only want to select the rows that are part of a 3 minute (minimum) consecutive sequence where amount >= 8 ?

I'm not sure about the performance but this seems to work:

Setup:

```sql
CREATE TABLE series
(
    id       INT  NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    date     DATE NOT NULL,
    time     TIME NOT NULL,
    datetime DATETIME GENERATED ALWAYS AS (TIMESTAMP(date, time)),
    amount   decimal(5, 2),
    INDEX (amount)
);

INSERT INTO series (date, time, amount)
VALUES ('2021-11-30', '14:40', 7),

       ('2021-11-30', '14:41', 8),
       ('2021-11-30', '14:42', 8),
       ('2021-11-30', '14:43', 8),
       ('2021-11-30', '14:44', 8),

       ('2021-11-30', '14:45', 7),

       ('2021-11-30', '14:46', 8),
       ('2021-11-30', '14:47', 8),
       ('2021-11-30', '14:48', 8),

       ('2021-11-30', '14:49', 7),

       ('2021-11-30', '14:50', 8),
       ('2021-11-30', '14:51', 8),

       ('2021-11-30', '14:52', 7)
;
```

The solution:

```sql
SELECT date, time, T.amount
FROM (SELECT date,
             time,
             datetime,
             amount,
             LAG(datetime, 2) OVER (order by datetime)  AS tmin2,
             LAG(datetime, 1) OVER (order by datetime)  AS tmin1,
             LEAD(datetime, 1) OVER (order by datetime) AS tplus1,
             LEAD(datetime, 2) OVER (order by datetime) AS tplus2
      FROM series
      WHERE amount >= 8) T
WHERE TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(T.datetime, T.tmin2)) = 120
   OR TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(T.datetime, T.tplus2)) = -120
   OR (TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(T.datetime, T.tmin1)) = 60 AND TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(T.datetime, T.tplus1)) = -60)
ORDER BY datetime;
```

Explanation:

- First we filter out the values < 8 using a `WHERE`-statement.
- Then we peek into the previous two and next two rows ordered by `datetime` to see if the current to is part of a 3 min sequence and filter based on that criteria.

Comment: This one is correct. I tested it against some extra scenarios. OP should accept this as the answer. Congrats @Sil, nice coding skills.

Comment: @sil thanks for this answer! I have mySQL 5.7 installed and will upgrade to 8.x to test this solution. I'll update after I test.

Comment: That’s right, I forgot to mention that window functions (Lag, Lead etc) are only supported as of MySQL version 8.

Comment: Your query worked exactly as required, thank you for responding! I did end up installing WAMPserver with mySQL 8.xx to run this on the database. The code performed well over the 2.4m rows.

Comment: Good to hear, you're very welcome. Thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution:

```
Table Definition : 
CREATE TABLE YourTbl (
  date date DEFAULT NULL,
  time time DEFAULT NULL,
  amount decimal(4,2) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;

INSERT INTO YourTbl VALUES
('2021-10-12','16:30', 20.40),
('2021-10-12','14:21', 19.34),
('2021-10-14','13:00', 15.40),
('2021-10-14','13:01', 9.34),
('2021-10-14','13:02', 10.12),
('2021-10-14','13:03', 7.44),
('2021-11-30', '14:44', 8.04),
('2021-11-30', '14:45', 9.41),
('2021-11-30', '14:46', 9.27),
('2021-11-30', '14:47', 10.54),
('2021-11-30', '14:48', 11.09),
('2022-03-13', '08:22', 36.44),
('2022-03-13', '08:23', 17.38),
('2022-03-13', '08:24', 11.86);
```

Lets test the query:

```
SELECT 
    date,time,amount FROM 
    (SELECT date,time,amount,
    LEAD(minute(time),1) OVER(PARTITION BY date ORDER BY time) as leadtime,
    LAG(minute(time),1) OVER(PARTITION BY date ORDER BY time) as lagtime,
    (minute(time) - LAG(minute(time),1) OVER(PARTITION BY date ORDER BY time)) as minute_forward_difference,
    (LEAD(minute(time),1) OVER(PARTITION BY date ORDER BY time) - minute(time)) as minute_backward_difference
    FROM YourTbl
    WHERE amount > 8.0
    ) as tblder
    WHERE (minute_forward_difference = 1) OR (minute_backward_difference = 1)
    GROUP BY date,time,amount;
```

Resultset:

[image: Click here to see image.]